# Invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist when trying to run container on Docker for Windows

Tags: powershell, docker, prometheus, docker-for-windows

I'm trying to run the Prometheus sample at https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/prometheus/#use-prometheus using Docker on Windows. I'm executing the following command:

```
docker service create --replicas 1 --name my-prometheus `
   --mount type=bind,source="C:/temp/prometheus.yml",destination=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml `
   --publish published=9090,target=9090,protocol=tcp `
   prom/prometheus
```

The error is: *invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist*

I'm pretty certain the file exists (`Test-Path` with PowerShell returns true).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

### Update

Running the same command with `mount type = volume` gives me the following error:

*C:/temp/prometheus.yml" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path"*

I am passing an host directory and `"C:/temp/prometheus.yml"` is an absolute path.

Comment: What if you are changing the mount type as volume --mount type=volume.

`Mount type=bind should be used on --mount type=bind,source=/path/on/host,destination=/path/in/container`

Comment: @RanadipDutta Thanks Tried it but still an error. See updated post,

Comment: Have you shared the C drive with Docker? https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#shared-drives

Comment: @BMitch yes, I have shared the C drive.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You may run into this on Windows after you change your Windows account password.

1. Open Docker for Windows Settings.
2. On Shared Drives tab click Reset credentials...
3. Share your drive once again.

Comment: I get this error without having changed my password, but after every reboot of my Windows 10 machine. Your solution worked, so this is good as a workaround. So what can I do to make DDEV and Docker not forget my Windows credentials?

Comment: https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/4709#issuecomment-406080690

Answer (score 2):

i got same error happened to me. as below picture, uncheck "Use Docker Compose V2" and it works for me. I wanted to share in case this might be the solution for somebody

[image]