# docker-compose up: path does not exist

Tags: django, windows, docker

I use Windows 7
Just follow my Django-project readme, but all I get is:
[image]

Comment: Please share the docker-compose file.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/EftCQRQ3 \ https://pastebin.com/wQfHvKHq \ https://pastebin.com/Tb0UE68H

Comment: Try following the steps mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51411304/8405123

Comment: is it possible to do on Windows 7? In all examples Docker for Windows is used